# Map Esc key in Vim

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

I'm a beginning Vim user. 
I hate pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, which is a little far on my T61. In order to return to command mode. How do I map it to <kbd>F4</kbd>?

Comment: Lot of ways you can replace esc: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a single session, you could just enter the following keystrokes exactly:

<kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

The <kbd>esc</kbd> key ensures that you're in command mode, colon starts a line command, and the `imap` maps the F4 key to ESCAPE.

However, if you want this retained for every session, you'll need to put in in your Vim start-up file.

The location of this varies depending on your environment (for my Linux box, it's at $HOME/.gvimrc for gvim, $HOME/.vimrc for vim). You'll need to find it and add the line:

```
imap <f4> <esc>
```

One trick you can use is to start a naked Vim session (`vim` without an argument) then enter

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

which will open up your current start-up file.

Also,

```
:echo $HOME
```

should tell you the location of it under Windows.

Comment: Note: on windows you want _vimrc

Answer (score 10):

Another way to exit insert mode is to use Ctrl+C. Not sure whether that helps in your situation though.

Comment: @Nick Presta: Perhaps you mean Ctrl+[, which is the same character as Esc in ASCII.

Answer (score 9):

Just like many Emacs users rebind their "Caps Lock" key to "Control", vimmers rebind their "Caps Lock" to "Escape".

...At least I do. And it works wonders.

Comment: How? `:ino <esc> <caps lock>`?

Comment: @isomorphismes

for windows: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_Windows

for linux:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc

Answer (score 5):

Try home row:

```
imap jj <Esc>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
imap <F4&> <ESC>
```

Comment: Type this into the `:` prompt (hit `:` and then type it), or put it on a line on its own in a file called `.vimrc` in your home directory.