# Unable to create a file from a path in Vim

Tags: vim, path

I have often PATHs for files which do not exist in my codes.

I run as my cursor is at a PATH which does not exist

```
CTRL-W f
```

I get

```
E447: Can't find file "~/bin/editors/emacs/python_mode" in path
```

The long way of creating new file is

```
Ctrl-W v
:args [copy_paste_the_path_with_mouse]
```

**Do you know any short way of creating a new file in Vim when you have PATHs for files in a file which do not exists yet?**

I would like to create a new file simply by

```
CTRL-W f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `:h E447` to look up the error message you received, you will see this:

```
...
If you do want to edit a new file, use:
    :e <cfile>
To make gf always work like that:
    :map gf :e <cfile><CR>
```

So try this:

```
:nmap <C-w>f :e <cfile><CR>
```

Comment: What does <cfile> mean? -- My docs says that it is about reading error files.

Comment: I tested it on Linux, Vim version 7.2.  You can see this doc here online (grep it for E447): http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/editing.html

Comment: Certain literals are expanded magically on the Vim commandline.  <cfile> is expanded to a string containing the pathname under the cursor in the currently active buffer.  See :h <cfile> and :h cmdline-special .

Comment: I found the same docs as you have in my OS/X. I made apparently a typo which gave me bad results. --- Thank you for your answers!

Comment: To get everything works fine, I recommend to use CTRL-W c, instead of CTRL-W f in creating new files.

Answer (score 1):

:e path_to_file 
:w!

I don't think there's a built in key combination for reading in the clipboard for the new file. 
You should be able to use key maps for this or a custom script.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764569/vim-key-map)  and [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) for more info.

Hope that helps

Comment: Problem: What is the code for coping the text between two spaces? If we know that, then the main problem is nearly solved.

Comment: `yiW` = "yank inner WORD", see `:h text-objects` for more info.

Comment: Also, <Ctrl+R>0 pastes the contents of register 0 while in insert mode, so `:e <Ctrl+R>0` will be what you want to do after the above.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to copy-paste with the mouse you can do `:edit ^R^P` to copy the path/filename at the cursor position into the command line.  For more info do `:help ^R^P`