# Having trouble executing <enter> automatically in a stored mapping in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard, hotkeys

I read [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764569/vim-key-map) on how to save a mapping permanently in vim. 
I went to `/etc/vim/vimrc` and added the `:map ,k :!python % <enter>` in the first line of the  file. When I open a new python file with vim the command responds by showing `:!python % <enter>` at the bottom of the screen. But it doesn't execute  automatically. How do I fix this command to execute 'enter' automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is to paste `:map :!python % <enter>` in `~/.vimrc`

Comment: You can also use `<cr>` Which I think is more common to see in other codes.

Answer (score 3):

i think you rather want to use a local version `~/.vimrc` for local settings than editing global settings in the file `/etc/vim/vimrc`. There you can add:

```
let maplocalleader=","
map <localleader>k :!python %<cr>
```

i would advise to not use `^M` as explained in ZyX comment to ghoti's answer [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766033/how-to-run-a-shell-command-through-vimscript)

**Edit**

ZyX' comment made me change the code above to

```
filetype plugin on
augroup ft_python
    au!
    au FileType python nnoremap ,k :!python %<cr>
augroup END
```

which keeps `,k` from messing with other stuff

- `filetype plugin on` says that we want to have things done if a file has a certain   filetype - in our case python
- `augroup ft_python` says i want to have a group of autocommands := "commands that are invoked when opening a file" with that group-name
- `au!` removes all autocommands
- `au Filetype python` declares an autocommand=`au` for all files of type python
- `augroup END` leaves the group ft_python and goes back to general settings

so this makes it possible to have `,k` act as 'compile' in python but when i accidentally press `,k` in another file say a c-source code, it does nothing (or the things i told `,k` to be for c-source code somewhere else in my .vimrc).

Comment: There is `nnoremap` for this sort of job (your mapping will be broken if user is exchanging the meanings of `:` and `;` which is sometimes done for increasing typing speed), change its meaning in visual mode and just useless in operator-pending mode. And I will also suggest `,k` directly, `maplocalleader` and `mapleader` are for [ft]plugins.

Comment: Your solution works but I don't understand it. So I prefer to just write `:map :!python % <cr>` in `~/.vimrc`(that also works as I wanted). I have no idea why writing that same line in `/etc/vim/vimrc` does not work properly though.

Comment: @Bentley4 I am pretty sure you had placed this mapping after a `set compatible` or before setting 'cpoptions' to a value that does contain `<`. You are not supposed to be placing something like a mapping to the `/etc/vim/vimrc` though.

Comment: There are also reasons why using `map` with no `nore` is to be prohibited and they are explained above (though first reason from your point of view changes to “one doesn’t really want to deduce which of existing mappings will break if he adds a new one”. With `noremap` they are just not going to break no matter what you add (except the new mapping with the same {lhs}, of course)).

Comment: Thnx Zyx. Ok, copy my answer below and change `map` with `noremap` and I will check that answer as the most suited answer to this stack thread.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a literal carriage return character instead - press Ctrl + V, then Enter when writing the map:

```
:map ,k :!python %^M
```

You'll see the carriage return shown as `^M` after typing the sequence Ctrl + V, then press the enter key.

That Ctrl + V key tells vim to insert the next character that you type.